# Deploying MEAN App to Heroku Gives H10 Error & 503 Status

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, mean-stack

I'm learning the MEAN stack and trying to understand how Heroku works at the same time. Using [this](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/) tutorial I put together a working application that runs on my machine.

When I try to follow [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction) tutorial and [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs) tutorial from heroku everything runs fine until I try to `heroku open`.

On herokuapp.com the page reads

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

A `heroku logs --tail` reads

`2015-08-14T19:31:20.459454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-coast-5761.herokuapp.com request_id=e09a152f-9b52-4433-be2d-5c5a40150da7 fwd="166.170.43.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=`

The repo is found [here](https://github.com/gh0st/flapper-news).

When I `heroku local web` the app runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some bad configuration. When I look at your repo the database configuration catch one's eye. In the last line of your **app.js** you have `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');`
Here is some code from the [heroku mongoose documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-mongoose)

```
var http = require ('http');             // For serving a basic web page.
var mongoose = require ("mongoose"); // The reason for this demo.

// Here we find an appropriate database to connect to, defaulting to
// localhost if we don't find one.
var uristring =
    process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
    process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
    'mongodb://localhost/HelloMongoose';

// The http server will listen to an appropriate port, or default to
// port 5000.
var theport = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Makes connection asynchronously.  Mongoose will queue up database
// operations and release them when the connection is complete.
mongoose.connect(uristring, function (err, res) {
if (err) {
   console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
} else {
  console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
}
});
```

It looks like your app crashed because of the missing database connection.

Comment: So you raise an important question with this post. I was under the impression it will construct my MongoDB for me. Now I think that Heroku does not know about my 'news' database. But isn't express/Angular supposed to do that for me?

Comment: So I can't even create a MongoDB without subscribing it looks like. Is there somewhere I can have the same features but have a free MongoDB?

Comment: Express did not setup your database neither angular. You have to wire up your app correctly. When you already using heroku you can add the monglab addon and go with the free plan. You don't have to pay for your development app. But you can always host it on your own servers. Maybe it's worth to look at some cheap hosting provider like digital ocean and dokku